# Python/lxml: Retrieving variable data

Tags: jquery, python, xpath, lxml

I want to parse some data from a website. However, there's a certain peculiarity:

There is a dropdown list (layed out using div and child a tags, made functional with a jQuery script). Upon selecting one of the values, a subsequent text field would change its value.

I want to retrieve the first dropdown value, and the respective text field, then the next dropdown value and the updated text field, and so forth.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens here is, upon selecting a value form the dropdown, an `AJAX` request is generated and gets the data.
You can analyze the request url in your browser. If you use firefox, use firebug and take a look at the `Net` tab, what requests are generating and what is the url. In google chorme, look in `Network` tab. If you want to parse the data you have to make a request in that url.